# VueJs cross origin issue

Tags: nginx, cross-domain, php-7.2

I have a project with VueJs and an API provider written in  PHP. Both has been installed on my localhost and I have defined a virtual host for my php project called "https://mydomain.loc".

The VueJs project can be reached at http://localhost:8080. When I want to send a post request to the api provider, I get an error as follow:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://socialbookmark.loc/api/profile'
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource.
```

My web server is also Nginx.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access a resource in same domain, say localhost, the methods go through easily, but when you try to access anything outside the domain, ex: localhost:8080 (VueJS app) is trying to request resource on server mydomain.com (PHP code), the access is block to prevent cross-origin access. This is a security measure.

In order to resolve requests from trusted domain, you need to provide access control headers.
Try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487)

Comment: can you share the response headers from network console?

Comment: Alternatively, you can set headers in PHP code from where you are sending response. Just keep it before sending the response.